# Django Model Instance as Template for Another Model that is populated by Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a workout tracking application where a user can:

1. Create an instance of an `ExerciseTemplate` model from a list of available `Exercise` models. I've created these as models so that the user can create custom `Exercises` in the future. There is also an `ExerciseInstance` which is to be used to track and modify the `ExerciseTemplate` created by the user, or someone else. I'm stripping the models of several unimportant fields for simplicity, but each contains the following:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    # Basic Variables
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ExerciseTemplate(models.Model):
    # Foreign Models

    workout = models.ForeignKey(
        'Workout',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True
    )

    exercise = models.ForeignKey(
        Exercise, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True
    )

    recommended_sets = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class ExerciseInstance(models.Model):

    """ Foreign Models """
    exercise_template = models.ForeignKey(
        ExerciseTemplate, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True
    )

    workout = models.ForeignKey(
        'Workout',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True
    )

    """ Fields """
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    reps = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

2. Create a `WorkoutInstance` from a `WorkoutTemplate`. The `WorkoutTemplate` is made up of `ExerciseTemplates`. But the `WorkoutInstance` should be able to take the `WorkoutTemplate` and populate it with `ExerciseInstances` based on the `ExerciseTemplates` in the `WorkoutTemplate`. Here are the models that I have so far:

```
class WorkoutTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    #category...
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(
        Exercise, 
        through=ExerciseTemplate
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WorkoutInstance(models.Model):

    # Foreign Models
    workout_template = models.ForeignKey(
        'WorkoutTemplate',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True
    )
```

But this is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to proceed. My intuition is one of the following:

1. I need to create a more simple architecture to do this. I'll take any suggestions.
2. I need to create a method within the model that solves this issue. If this is the case, I'm not sure what this would actually look like.

Comment: Questions in SO are asked one at a time, you should ask one question, and also what do you mean by this  `I need to create a method within the model that solves this issue`, here what issue you are talking about?

Comment: Hey, so I'm not asking two questions here. I'm asking what the best path forward would be. The two points are there as options that I've identified that might be possible solutions. Either I (1) create a more simple architecture that solves this problem or (2) create a method for one of the models (```WorkoutInstance``` probably) that solves the issue. Does that add clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new WorkoutInstance object which references a given WorkoutTemplate object you get all its related ExerciseTemplate objects.
Then you just create a new object (row) for each ExerciseInstance in another model (table)

If you link your ExerciseInstance to WorkoutInstance via 'workout' you could do something like:

```
wt = WorkoutTemplate.get(id=1) 
wi = WorkoutInstance.create(workout_template=wt) 

for e in wt.exercisetemplate_set.all:
    ExerciseInstance.create(exercise_template=e, workout=wi)
```

You can implent this in the method that creates the new WorkoutInstance or take a look at [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/optimization/#create-in-bulk

Comment: Hey David, your suggestion worked! Thanks for helping me through this.